# where can find a example on adding UIButton in each UITableCell

Tags: uibutton

Where can find a example on adding UIButton in each UITableCell?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `UIbutton` and jus `addSubView` to the `cell` it will work fine.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UIImageView * accerTypeImage;
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        UIButton *button = [[UIButton allo] init];
        button.frame = //give the frame in UITableViewCell.
        button.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell addSubView:button];
        [button release];
return cell;

        }
```